# Will React.lazy improve React Native performance?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

I'm wondering if `React.lazy` improves performance in React Native apps.

```
const Warning = React.lazy(() => import('./Warning'));
...
render() {
  return (
    ...
    {
      {this.state.count > 10 ? (
          <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
            <Warning />
          </React.Suspense>
        ) : null}
    }
  )
}
```

I understand that the above using **dynamic loading of Webpack bundles** om the ReactJS side and I'm wondering if it helps on the React Native side?

Essentially, we bundled all the JS code together and shipped it together to user device. All the JS code is already there, sitting on the user's device. I wonder if `React.lazy` will improve performance, and how.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to improve anything but you can't be sure without benchmarks.

Comment: If the performance not gonna be improve even if academically speaking, I guess I'll just save the hassle. Reason is I'm still very new into `webpack` and still trying to figure out how the `bundle` thing works in general. Anyway thanks for your input @estus !

Answer (score 5):

No definitely not. But it may improve your app's startup time.
If you got many screens then your app startup time will go slow without lazy import.
Check your app startup time without lazy import and after implementing the lazy import. Also it saves some RAM space.

Answer (score 2):

It works, but it is not used mainly for app start but expensive loading components.

```
const SomeHeavyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('../SomeHeavyComponent'));

<View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
    <React.Suspense fallback={MyLoader()}>
      <SomeHeavyComponent />
    </React.Suspense>
  </View>
```

It is useful when using react-navigation tabs, and you want to switch between tabs quickly and don't wait for HeavyComponent to render before tab switch.

Answer (score 1):

React Native doesn't have the same performance considerations as a web application, so the same techniques do not necessarily apply.

In React Native, all of the JS code is bundled together and shipped with the app when it is installed. So, some techniques like code-splitting and lazy loading won't have the same impact on performance.

Therefore there are some interesting packages like (if you don't use Hermes):

- [react-native-bundle-splitter](https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-bundle-splitter)

> Decrease your start up time and RAM memory consumption by an application via splitting JS bundle by components and navigation routes.

- [re.pack](https://github.com/callstack/repack)

> A Webpack-based toolkit to build your React Native application with full support of Webpack ecosystem.

To improve performance, you could also use some new concurrent features from React 18 and the React Native New Architecture:

- [startTransition](https://react.dev/reference/react/startTransition)
- [usetransition](https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition)
- [useDeferredValue](https://react.dev/reference/react/useDeferredValue)
- [Suspense](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense)